# C++ циклический сдвиг влево

Tags: c++, алгоритм

> Дан линейный массив на N элементов. Выполнить циклический сдвиг всех его элементов на один влево начиная с первого нулевого элемента. Нулевой элемент обязательно существует.
>   input: 1 0 3 4 5
>   output: 1 3 4 5 0

Написал код, все ручные проверки проходит, но сайт не принимает как верное решение.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n,from;
  cin >> n;
  int arr[n];
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cin >> arr[i];
    if (arr[i]==0) from=i;
  }
  for(int i=from+1;i<n;i++)
  {
    arr[i-1]=arr[i];
  }
  arr[n-1]=0;
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @Kromster код привёл, я не могу найти ошибку в алгоритме

Comment: Для того чтобы найти ошибку, надо также приложить код теста, который валится ;-)

Comment: @Kromster сайт с олимпиадными задачками наподобие acmp.ru, пишет только "не пройдено"

Comment: О том и речь, что подобный вопрос плох для SO. Вы пишете "вот мой код, я его отправляю в черный ящик и он отвечает что в коде ошибка, но не говорит какая и где. Исправьте мне код, так, чтобы он понравился черному ящику."

Comment: `if (arr[i]==0) from=i;` - какая-то ерунда

Comment: Да, добавил && from==-1 и int from=-1

Comment: Опять `int arr[n];` - это не С++.

Comment: @AnT, я не понимаю чем же это не  С++?...  В  С++. вполне могут использоваться  С_массивы, другое дело, что  возможности С++. позволяют делать то же самое гораздо проще...  Поясните пожалйста

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Массив с размером, определяемым в рантайм. Есть такое в стандарте (не в расширениях)?

Comment: @MBo, да, спасибо, я просто не заметил, кинув взгляд...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Массив с размером, задаваемым *переменной* - это VLA из языка С. В языке С++ нет VLA и размер массива может задаваться только *константным* целочисленным выражением.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если будет несколько нулей, запомнится *(как говорил Штирлиц)* последняя позиция :

```
 for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cin >> arr[i];
    if (arr[i]==0) from=i;
  }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Во первых обратите внимание на комментарий: "Массив с размером, задаваемым переменной - это VLA из языка С. В языке С++ нет VLA и размер массива может задаваться только константным целочисленным выражением. – `AnT`  ". Во вторых, инструментами C++,  это можно написать гораздо проще. Например:

```
std::valarray<int> v{1, 6, 0, 11, 3, 0, 4, 5};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) 
        if(!v[i]) {
            const std::slice_array<int>& s = v[std::slice(i, v.size() - i, 1)];
            std::valarray<int> v1(s);
            s = v1.cshift(1); 
            //т.е. в данный срез копируем циклически сдвинутую 
            //последовательность этого же среза
            break;
        }        
    for (int i : v)
        cout << i << ' ';
```